# Python 3.5: Is it possible to align punctuation (e.g. £, $) to the left side of a word using regex?

Tags: python-3.x

As part of my code, I need to align things like the pound sign to the left of a string. For example my code starts with:

```
"A price of £ 8 is roughly the same as $ 10.23!"
```

and needs to end with:

```
"A price of £8 is roughly the same as $10.23!"
```

I've created the following function to solve this however I feel that it is very inefficient and was wondering if there was a way to do this with regular expressions in Python?

```
for i in sentence:

if i == "(" or i == "{" or i == "[" or i == "£" or i == "$":
    if i != len(sentence):
    corrected_sentence.append(" ")

    corrected_sentence.append(i)

else:
    corrected_sentence.append(i)
```

What this is doing right now is going through the 'sentence' list where I have split up all of the words and punctuation and t then reforming this followed by a space EXPECT where the listed characters are used and adding to another list to be made into a single string again.

I only want to do this with the characters I have listed above (so I need to ignore things like full stops or exclamation marks etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the brackets, but from the description you can use a regex to find and replace whitespace preceded by the characters (lookbehind) and followed by a digit (lookahead).

```
>>> print(re.sub(r"(?<=[\{\[£\$])\s+(?=\d)", "", "A price of £ 8 is roughly the same as $ 10.23!"))
A price of £8 is roughly the same as $10.23!
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted brackets (only the left side in this case) to do the same thing e.g. a string such as "( test)" should become "(test)". How would I integrate that into your code aswell?

Comment: Is there any case where you want to keep the spaces, e.g., "Price in £ or $ quoted"? If not, change it to `r"(?<=[\{\[£\$])\s+"`. - just remove the lookahead.

Comment: That won't really come up so the code you've provided works fine; thanks!